# Open the popups of all markers that are visible on the map with a zoom > 14

Tags: leaflet, popup

I need to open all the markers that are visible on the map at Zoom > 14. I am using leaflet.CircleMarker
Init map

```
var tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Points &copy 2012 LINZ'
    })
    var before = '';
    var id = '';
    var province = '';
    var school = [];
    var markers = new L.FeatureGroup();
    var info = '';
    var currtBtn = 0;

    var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [21.028511, 105.804817],
        minZoom: 2,
        zoom: 10
    });
```

Custom Map

```
var MyCustomMarker = L.CircleMarker.extend({

        bindPopup: function (htmlContent, options) {

            if (options && options.showOnMouseOver || options.zoomend) {
                    // call the super method
                    L.CircleMarker.prototype.bindPopup.apply(this, [htmlContent, options]);

                    // unbind the click event
                    this.off("click", this.openPopup, this);

                    // bind to mouse over
                    this.on("mouseover", function (e) {
                        // get the element that the mouse hovered onto
                        var target = e.originalEvent.fromElement || e.originalEvent.relatedTarget;
                        var parent = this._getParent(target, "leaflet-popup");

                        // check to see if the element is a popup, and if it is this marker's popup
                        if (parent == this._popup._container)
                            return true;

                        // show the popup
                        this.openPopup();

                    }, this);
                    // and mouse out
                    this.on("mouseout", function (e) {

                        // get the element that the mouse hovered onto
                        var target = e.originalEvent.toElement || e.originalEvent.relatedTarget;

                        // check to see if the element is a popup
                        if (this._getParent(target, "leaflet-popup")) {

                            L.DomEvent.on(this._popup._container, "mouseout", this._popupMouseOut, this);
                            return true;

                        }

                        // hide the popup
                        this.closePopup();

                    }, this);

                }

            },

            _popupMouseOut: function (e) {

                // detach the event
                L.DomEvent.off(this._popup, "mouseout", this._popupMouseOut, this);

                // get the element that the mouse hovered onto
                var target = e.toElement || e.relatedTarget;

                // check to see if the element is a popup
                if (this._getParent(target, "leaflet-popup"))
                    return true;

                // check to see if the marker was hovered back onto
                if (target == this._icon)
                    return true;

                // hide the popup
                this.closePopup();

            },

            _getParent: function (element, className) {

                var parent = (element && element.parentNode)?element.parentNode : null;

                while (parent != null) {

                    if (parent.className && L.DomUtil.hasClass(parent, className))
                        return parent;

                    parent = parent.parentNode;

                }

                return false;

            }

        });
```

Add Marker

```
var markerarray = rs;
                for (var i = 0; i < markerarray.length; ++i)
                {
                    if (markerarray[i].lat && markerarray[i].lng) {
                        if (markerarray[i].cap == '1' && markerarray[i].cap1 == '1') {
                            var marker = new MyCustomMarker([markerarray[i].lat, markerarray[i].lng], {color: 'rgb(255, 78, 80)', fillColor: 'rgb(255, 78, 80)',fillOpacity: 1, opacity:0.4,radius:4, weight : 6});
                        }
                        if (markerarray[i].cap == '2') {
                            var marker = new MyCustomMarker([markerarray[i].lat, markerarray[i].lng], {color: 'blue', fillColor: 'blue',fillOpacity: 1, opacity:0.4,radius:4, weight : 6});
                        }
                        if (markerarray[i].cap == '3') {
                            var marker = new MyCustomMarker([markerarray[i].lat, markerarray[i].lng], {color: 'yellow', fillColor: 'yellow',fillOpacity: 1, opacity:0.4,radius:4, weight : 6});
                        }
                        if (markerarray[i].cap == '1' && markerarray[i].mam_non == '1') {
                            var marker = new MyCustomMarker([markerarray[i].lat, markerarray[i].lng], {color: 'green', fillColor: 'green',fillOpacity: 1, opacity:0.4,radius:4, weight : 6});
                        }
                        if (markerarray[i].dai_hoc == '1' || markerarray[i].cao_dang == '1' || markerarray[i].trung_cap == '1') {
                            var marker = new MyCustomMarker([markerarray[i].lat, markerarray[i].lng], {color: 'orange', fillColor: 'orange',fillOpacity: 1, opacity:0.4,radius:4, weight : 6});
                        }
                        if(marker){
                            marker.bindPopup('This is ok', {autoClose: false, autoPan: false,zoomend: true});
                            markers.addLayer(marker);
                        }
                    }
                }
                map.addLayer(markers);
```

Comment: No, your link is leaflet use leaflet.markercluster plugin
I am using leafet.CircleMarker

Comment: If you look at the code and try to understand it, you'll se that the solution itself had nothing to do with marker cluster plugin. Have a look at the code from `var bounds;` statement onwards.